# How to get the numbers in XQuery that are in the same node and separated by spaces or '-'(minus sign)?

Tags: xml, xquery

Like the title

```
<test>

 <num>1 5 7</num>

 <num>4-2</num>

 .....

</test>
```

how to get the sum for each num tag

i have tried to change the string like from {1 5 7} to {1+5+7} then use sum or number function
but it did't work

expected get

```
<test>

 <num>13</num>

 <num>2</num>

 .....

</test>
```

or other format
thx

Comment: The title says, “separated by spaces”, which isn't the case for `4-2`. Could you please fix either the example or the title?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Martin Honnen's and Mads Hansen's answers were missing the actual querying and result returning part. I also added some extra lines with useful variable names for readability.

```
let $data :=
  <test>
    <num>1 5 7</num>
    <num>4-2</num>
  </test>

return
  <result>{
    for $num in $data/num
    let $normalized := replace($num/text(), '-', ' -')
    let $numbers := tokenize($normalized, ' ') ! number(.)
    return
      <sum>{sum($numbers)}</sum>
  }</result>
```

Comment: Now I got how it work , thanks for u :D

Comment: @Ra1nForest Please mark one of the postings as the answer and upvote all helpful ones.

Answer (score 2):

`sum(tokenize(<num>1 5 7</num>)!xs:decimal(.))` gives `13`. It is not clear how the example `<num>4-2</num>` and the sum (?) `2` fits in.

Comment: `sum( tokenize(replace(<num>4-2</num>, "-", " -"), " ") ! number(.) )`

Comment: @MadsHansen, that looks tricky but might work to produce the shown result.

Comment: it's just minus sign    it's my bad for not stating